# finite state markov chain stationary distribution existence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Here is a fact from *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Prof. Sidney I. Resnick: A finite state, irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain is always positive recurrent and the stationary distribution always exists.

Does this mean that a finite state Markov chain which is irreducible and aperiodic does not have a transient or null recurrent state? Could someone help me prove this?

Comment: Finite, irreducible means you can get to any state in at most size of the state space number of steps with positive probability. Hence...

Comment: @ A.S.: I think you stated a definition for irreducibility for finite markov chains. I cannot see a rigorous proof from here.

Comment: What is a probability that $T_x>N$? What about $T_x>2N$? What about $T_x>kN$?

Comment: @A.S. The probability $P(T_x > kN) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ because it is irreducible and finite state. So it would return to $x$ in finite time.

Comment: You are left to show that $E(T_x)<\infty$.

Comment: @ A.S.: $E(T_x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nP(T_x = n)$. The terms in the tail go to zero. Is it sufficient to conclude that it only finite terms in the sum matter.

Comment: No. For example $\sum 1/n$ diverges while $sum 1/n^2$ converges.

Comment: @A.S.: Any further hints. Have we made use of periodicity yet?